# I need to create a python function that takes an input and doubles the number three times using a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having an issues creating a function that takes one number as its input and doubles that number three times using a loop.

For example taking the input 2 and returning 4,8,16

What I've tried so far is the following

```
def doubles(i):
    for n in range(2:5):
        doubled_num = i ** n
    return doubled_num

i = 2
output_num = doubles(i)
print output_num
```

Comment: def doubles(i):
    for n in range(2:5):
        doubled_num = i ** n
        return doubled_num

i = 2
output_num = doubles(i)

print output_num

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I need to figure out how to properly enter code into the comments here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help look here for some help

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(n):
    n_d = n*2 
    n_tri = n_d*2 
    fin_n = n_tri*2
    return n_d,n_tri,fin_n
In [6]: f(2)
(4, 8, 16)
```

Using a loop like your own example:

```
def f(n):
    result=[]
    for i in range(3): # loop 3 times
        n*=2 # n doubles each time through the loop
        result.append(n) #add new value of n to result list 
    return result
In [10]: f(2)
[4, 8, 16]
```

Range starts at 0, going 0,1,2, it does not include the upper end.

Using `n*=2`  is the same as `n = n * 2`

Answer (score 0):

Concise (but not very efficient):

```
def doubles(i, n=3):
    return [i * 2**x for x in range(1, n+1)]
```

then

```
>>> doubles(2)
[4, 8, 16]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def doubles(num):
    """Return the result of multiplying an input number by 2."""
    return num * 2

# Call doubles() to double the number 2 three times
my_num = 2
for i in range(0, 3):
    my_num = doubles(my_num)
    print(my_num)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).